# Member functions via a pointer

Tags: c++

Hello I have a method to pass in a variable, is it possible to do it without puut the method cpu_kernel_trainMe in static ?

```
class StarPuNet
{
 public:

   void cpu_kernel_trainMe(void *buffers[], void *cl_arg) {}

   int initStarPu() 
   {
     starpu_codelet_init(&cl_);
     cl_.cpu_funcs     [0] = cpu_kernel_trainMe;   //The problem is here
     cl_.cpu_funcs_name[0] = "cpu_kernel_trainMe";
     cl_.nbuffers          = 3;
     cl_.modes         [0] = STARPU_R;
     cl_.modes         [1] = STARPU_R;
     cl_.modes         [2] = STARPU_W;
     cl_.name              = "trainMe";
     return 0;
   };

 private:
   starpu_codelet cl_;
}
```

The compiler :

```
In member function ‘int StarPuNet::initStarPu()’:
error: cannot convert ‘StarPuNet::cpu_kernel_trainMe’ from type 
‘void (StarPuNet::)(void**, void*)’ to type ‘starpu_cpu_func_t’ {aka ‘void (*)(void**, void*)’}
```

I also tried  :

```
cl_.cpu_funcs[0] = void (*cpu_kernel_trainMe)(void **, void *);
```

The compiler :

```
error: invalid use of member function ‘void StarPuNet::cpu_kernel_trainMe(void**, void*)’ 
(did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
```

Here the doc for [cpu_funcs](https://files.inria.fr/starpu/doc/html/group__API__Codelet__And__Tasks.html#a593418a8961318e4085177abeeaa43ad)

Best regard

Comment: A pointer to a non-member function is not the same as a pointer to a non-static member function. The difference is that a non-static member function needs an object to be called with. If such an object isn't needed, then use a `static` member function.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you *need* an object (for access to other members, for example) then you might be able to use a `static` wrapper function, which is passed a pointer to the object as some kind of user-data. Then cast this user-data to a pointer to the object and call the actual member function. If the API you use have support for user-data like that I don't know, you have to read its documentation and examples, but the `cl_arg` argument indicate there's some such support.

Comment: This is a C++ FAQ.  Search the internet for "C++ FAQ member function pointer.